# General Mysql database maintenance advice

Tags: mysql, database

I have about 40 databases with the same schema. What can I so to ensure these databases run smoothly?

Should I be optimizing tables regularly?
How can I detect table crashes?

Comment: To start with, I'd recommend using InnoDB engine if you're not already for it has better crash recovery.

Comment: You may want to try posting this on [Database Administrators](http://dba.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

As described in detail within the below article, the bare minimum actions you should perform include,

1. database backup
2. check table integrity for errors
3. optimize tables (varies between MyISAM and InnoDB)
4. analyze

http://www.laurencegellert.com/2011/07/mysql-maintenance-tasks-for-innodb-with-mysql-5-1/